# JUnit - NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java, maven, junit, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to learn unit testing and Maven, to do so I'm using JUnit and writing simple random name generator. I have following class:

```
public class Database {

  public String readRandomName(String url) throws FileNotFoundException {
     int sum = calculateFileLines(url);
     int lines = (int) (Math.random()*sum);
     File file = new File(url);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
     for (int i=0; i<lines;i++){
         scanner.nextLine();
     }
     return scanner.nextLine();
  }

  public int calculateFileLines(String url) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int sum = 0;
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(url))){
        while(scanner.hasNextLine() && scanner.nextLine().length()!=0){
            ++sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

When I run simple test like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Database database = new Database();
    database.readRandomName("names/maleNamesPL.txt");
}
```

It works perfectly, but when I tried to write JUnit test with assertion there is an unexpected failure which I don't understand. This is test code:

```
@Test
public void readRandomNameTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Database database = new Database();
    Assert.assertNotNull("Should be some name", database.readRandomName("names/maleNamesPL.txt"));
}
```

And the results:

```
Tests in error: 
readRandomNameTest(DatabaseTest): No line found
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: It would help if you'd show the exact line that throws the `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: also, your main works perfectly, but it didn't have any assertions or sysout

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
- *UnitTest* should **never** use any resource outside the JVMs memory. Therefore you should not create the `Scanner` object inside your code but pass it in as a parameter into your code instead of the `String` containing the files path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `nextLine()` and it's throwing an exception when there's no line, exactly as the javadoc describes. It will never return `null`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

With `Scanner` you need to check if there is a next line with `hasNextLine()`

so the loop becomes

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String str=scanner.nextline();
    //...
}
```